# Is assigning multiple values on the same line in Python clear?

Tags: python

With Python I've been assigning multiple values on the same line in groups:

```
class GameObject:
    def __init__(self, image, x=0, y=0):
        self.image, self.x, self.y = image, x, y
        self.vel, self.vel_x, self.vel_y = 0, 0, 0
```

Is there anything wrong with this? Does it look unclear?

Comment: its perfectly fine ... it also makes the code a little harder to read

Comment: It is perfectly fine to do so.  There is nothing wrong, although the readability decreases this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, it's fine. I'd only do it for related variables, though. It's reasonable to combine `x` and `y` in one line, but `image` doesn't really fit with those two. You might split them up.

```
self.image = image
self.x, self.y = x, y
```